# Showing only part of a table using Client-side technologies, i.e. Javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination, client-side

When the webpage is loaded, a table with roughly 50 rows and 288 columns is loaded, but only about 5 rows and 25 columns are shown. We are trying to implement navigation of the rows and columns, pressing down moves up only 2 rows and show 2 new rows, or moving right shows 12 new columns and hides the 12 left most.

We always want to show the headers and the first column, but the rest, we want to be able to control what the client sees using client-side code to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a datatable Javascript widget. There are many available, both commercial and open source.

I like and use the [YUI datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) Excellent documentation and community.

Comment: This looks very interesting, but we don't want to use 3rd party software if we can help it. We are keeping it in our head that this is available to us, but we're still looking. Thanks.